# Node JS Process Crashes without Error Logging

Tags: node.js, express, crash

I'm trying to run a really simple implementation of a Node JS server using Express to serve EJS content. When I start the server and it runs perfectly fine, but then unexpectedly crashes after a while. Sometimes it will crash within a half an hour, while other times it has stayed up for 4-6 hours at a time.

I can't seem to pin down a source of the error because my logs do not contain any stack traces.

I've taken [this answer's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19882980) and I have this:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (exception) {
    console.log(exception); // to see your exception details in the console
});
```

and I've also overloaded the `console` methods to log to a file, like so:

```
console.log = function(d) {
    log(d);
};

console.error = function(d) {
    log(d);
};

function log(message) {
    log_file.write(util.format(message) + '\n');
    log_stdout.write(util.format(message) + '\n');
}
```

Still, the server crashes without reporting anything. I've also tried to create a Node `domain`:

```
var domain = require('domain');
var d = domain.create();

d.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

If I had to take a guess, I would imagine this error might be caused by the process running out of memory, as I am running all of this on the Raspberry Pi model B version 2, but I can't be sure. If it was truly running out of memory, I would expect to see:

> FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory

reported somewhere in my logs.

My server itself is actually quite simple:

```
// Create Express and set up the EJS view engine
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use("/resources", express.static(__dirname + "/resources"));

// Setup the index page view
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(getFormattedDate() + req.method + " " + req.url + " by " + req.connection.remoteAddress);
    res.render('pages/index', {
        title: "James Taylor",
        content: formattedContent
    });
});

app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error();
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    if (err.status == 404) {
        console.error(getFormattedDate() + err + req.url);
        res.set("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        res.status(err.status);
        res.send(err.message);
    } else {
        console.error(err);
        return next();
    }
});
```

In the meantime, I've been able to get around this issue by using [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever), which seems to work nicely.

I'd appreciate any advice you could give about trying to troubleshoot this problem. It just doesn't seem right that I have to have all this infrastructure surrounding a perpetually crashing server.

Comment: I would recommend you to use the default console log methods and run the program manually in a cmd so you can see the console log after the crash.

Comment: Yeah, I'm already doing that. The problem with that, though, is a shell would have to have the Node process in the foreground for 2-4 hours. I'm running this off of a Raspberry Pi and keeping an ssh connection for this long idling wouldn't be practical.

Comment: I see... Have you tried running the same program in a normal computer? If you are right about the memory leak maybe you can try monitoring the memory usage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018588/how-to-monitor-the-memory-usage-of-node-js

Comment: @JamesTaylor hey, did you find a solution to your problem? My server also crashes without showing any error, like you.